# How to make a call after create call in Spring web flux?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-webflux, java-11

I have a scenario where a user after getting saved in the table, a role has to be created, the role table has a foreign key reference which is userId.

I tried writing some code when I debug I could see the method getting called, but the query isn't executing.
Following is my code,

**Handler**

```
Mono<User> userResponse = service.create(user);
                    return ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(userResponse, User.class).switchIfEmpty(ServerResponse.badRequest().build());
```

**Service**

```
Mono<User> user = this.repository
                .create(User.builder().userName(user.getUserName()).build())
                .convert().with(toMono());
        return user.map(u -> {
            this.saveRoleForUser(u);
            return u;
        });

public void saveRoleForUser(User u) {
        this.repository.getRole("roleName").flatMap(i -> {
            return this.repository.createRole(Roles.of(null, u.userId, i.getRoleId));
        });
    }
```

I could see the **getRole("roleName")** is getting called in the repository, but the query isn't executing.

There's no error in the repository, I guess it's because of the thread blocking that's not allowing this query to execute. I tried searching for the solution but using flatMap should solve the problem is what I got to know.
I even tried calling "**saveRoleForUser**" from the handler class, that isn't working too.

**Repository**

```
public Uni<Role> getRole(String roleName) {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = this.sessionFactory.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Role> query = cb.createQuery(Role.class);
        Root<Role> root = query.from(Role.class);
        query.where(cb.equal(root.get("roleName"), roleName));

        return this.sessionFactory.withSession(session -> session.createQuery(query).getSingleResultOrNull()).onItem()
                .ifNull().switchTo(Uni.createFrom().item(Role.builder().build()));
    }
```

PS: The user is getting created, I'm not getting any errors or exceptions.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In reactor "Nothing happens until you subscribe" and nothing is subscribing to the `Mono` created inside `saveRoleForUser`

Comment: @MichaelMcFadyen when I subscribe, this is the error I get "org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.model.User" I understand that it's because it is trying to persist the same user object, how can I avoid that?

Comment: you need to read the basics of reactor. You have several problems `this.repository.getRole` here you are breaking the reactive chain. You must ALWAYS take care of your returns, here you are not returning, you are doing "void" which you cant do. You are breaking the reactive chain `saveRoleForUser`must rerturn a `Mono<Void>` dont use void functions in reactive. You clearly havnt read the documentation for reactor

Comment: @Shinchan to me, your question seems unrelated to the question asked above. If you have a further question to ask, please raise a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's is some sample code of ideally what the code should look like.
The most important thing to note here, is that we will now be subscribing to the `Mono` returned from `saveRoleForUser` which ensures the operations inside that function will get executed after the subscription occurs.

```java
public Mono<User> createUser() {
        return this.repository
                .create(User.builder().userName(user.getUserName()).build())
                .convert().with(toMono())
                .flatMap(u -> this.saveRoleForUser(u));
}

public Mono<User> saveRoleForUser(User u) {
        this.repository.getRole("roleName").flatMap(i -> {
            return this.repository.createRole(Roles.of(null, u.userId, i.getRoleId));
        }).thenReturn(u);
}
```